# Can R CMD check run examples/tests in parallel (on Windows)?

Tags: r

R CMD check takes a significant amount of time to complete on one of my packages because there are many examples/tests to run.  Perhaps there's a way to run in parallel?

I stumbled upon this post which seems to have a solution for R CMD install on linux (I can't see how it would work on Windows):
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/parallel-build-for-package-equivalent-of-make-j8-td921920.html

Is there a solution for parallel R CMD check on Windows?

Comment: The solution in that post isn't Linux-specific; but it will only work with packages that contain compiled code (C, C++, Fortran).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hack, but you could take the tests out of the `tests` directory and put them somewhere else that they won't get run automatically (e.g. `inst/tests`), then use your own, parallelizable, framework (e.g. `make` run in parallel: http://dannythorpe.com/2008/03/06/parallel-make-in-win32/ may be relevant) to run the tests ... this won't help for examples, though.

Comment: Ben - My tests currently live in inst/tests, so check there.  Is your suggestion to build a version of R where R CMD check runs in parallel?  I was hoping such a version exists or that there was a way to call R CMD check and tell it to run tests in parallel.

Comment: I thought that `R CMD CHECK` only automatically tested code found in `tests` (not `inst/tests`), but maybe I was wrong about that.  In any case I think the answer to your question above is "no" ... If I were **really** desperate for this I would look in `tools:::.check_packages` and see if there were an easy way to hack it to use the `multicore` package ...

Comment: I have a file in tests that calls the function testthat::test_package, which in turn runs tests in inst/tests =)  This was the best-practice guildelines for using testthat.  I think the hack is beyond my skill level.  Thanks for confirming that there is no out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score -1):

A completely different approach would be to use the cacheSweave package, which caches the unchanging parts of your code from run-to-run.  If you are tweaking some code but most of it is unchanged, this could save a lot of time.  If plots are what's slowing things down however, cacheSweave won't help much (as explained in the vignette).

Comment: OK, commenting on my own post I guess I should add I'm not sure cacheSweave works for R CMD check, but it certainly works for Sweaving other documents.  I'm sure someone will clarify this.

Comment: Bryan - I'm not using sweave at all...my issue is with R examples/tests that are purely computational

Comment: Got it. I was thinking of R CMD check working up a vignette, but you are just worried about the code in help page examples.  Sorry, I don't have an idea for that :-(